# Calling function from model into controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to call function from model into the controller in foreach loop?

This is my model

```
class Order extends Eloquent
{
    public static function getData($data)
    {
        // function code 
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying in my controller

```
$get = Order::all();
foreach ($get->getData($get->details) as $itemId => $details) {
    dd($details);
}
```

This produce error

> Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getData()

I've tried exact same code in my blade and there is working without any issue.

So, how I'm suppose to call and use the function in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getData()` function is declared as static in your class

```
public static function getData($data)
{
    // function code 
}
```

So it should be called using class name as `Order::getData($get->details)`

```
foreach (Order::getData($get->details) as $itemId => $details) {
    dd($details);
}
```

Comment: It's return `ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$details`

Comment: check what you are getting in `$get` variable

Comment: I'm getting all data as `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#522 (1) ....`

Comment: And if is matter `details` holds data as array?

Comment: It turn out that I need to `json_decode` it first. Thanks for the help